# Get the product_retailer_id / Content ID for a specific product

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I'm trying to get the product_retailer_id (or as it's displayed in the catalog - Content ID) but it is not showing when I use the product_endpoint

[image: 1]

I've used the graph API explorer and included all items that can be included for a specific product:

[image: 2]

there's retailer_id

[image: 3]

But that returns a null

I used the graph api explorer and included all potential fields for a product but none of the results return the field I'm looking for.